# can we do some change to the object being returned at runtime

Tags: java, object, runtime

is there a possibility to do some changes in object at runtime.

my problem is i have one class which returns me the instance of logger. and that class contains only one public method which returns the logger. below is the class..

```
public class LoggerManager {

    public Logger getLogger(String FQCN) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FQCN);
            logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            return logger;
    }
}
```

now if i want to change the returning object at runtime,

which means that the logger object which is set to level INFO, i want to change that one to DEBUG.. during program execution only when this code is called at a particular time... without changing the code anywhere.. some thing like that...

```
logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

can i achieve this, by any means??

as this class is used everywhere within my code.. about a 1000 places, without changing the code by....some means can i achieve this...

Comment: i read this 3 times and i still don't understand your question.  can you elaborate?

Comment: @amir : i have updated,, please tell me if now u are able to understand or not??..

Comment: Could you explain why this should not work? Dont get it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are asking if you can change the behavior of the `getLogger(String)` method without changing the class.  The simple answer is "no you cannot".

There are a couple of tricks you could try:

- Putting a different version of the class ahead of the current one in the application's classpath ahead of the current version.
- Using BCEL or something to modify the class bytecodes prior to loading.

However, both of these amount to changing the class.

I think your simplest approach is to modify the `LogManager` class so that you can generate loggers with different levels.  With a little thought you should be able to come up with a solution that doesn't impact the rest of your codebase significantly.

However, it is also worth nothing that the normal way to set logging levels is to use a configuration file, rather than explicit calls to `setLevel` in the application.

Comment: (use a configuration file ... or [just] DI)

Comment: @pst - using DI to set logging levels would probably be a bad idea.  Normal practice is to use the logging configuration files ... that's where most people *expect* to find this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a possibility to do some changes in object at runtime

Yes, you can make changes on `Objects` that are returned from method calls.

It is difficult to understand what you want to do.  If you set the debug level on the returned logger, it should be set for all places in your running vm that request a `Logger` with the same `FQCN` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the desired value before your call, and back to normal afterwards.
Somme logging classes allow this.

```
I can't be specific here because your didn't say exactly what your Logger class is (Log4j ?).
```

This logger class seems to be called as a static method.
Therefore, if you have any threads in your system (if using Tomcat for example, or using a background thread), modifying the level is unsafe (it will modify for you but also for all threads).

---

However, the usual option to your problem is not to change the level.
When you want a log to appear, either :

1. Log at a level that appears
2. Choose a different logger (each one can be configured to a specific level).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with AOP but it is rather compilcated. AOP allows you to handle both pre and post method invocation.

I am not sure why you have to getLogger more than 1000 places in your single project. Do you have more than 1000 classes? Normally, you only need to call it once per class. I would also change the code and redesign overcalling to this method.